# django-rest-swagger==2.1.1 query parameter

Tags: django, swagger

i have an api(web service) in django like this:
http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/back_office/appointments/days/?branch=1
that in swagger i want to input query parameter named branch but don't work this(all of my Apis have same problem!!).

before, i use older version of swagger and for enter query parameters use like --param_name syntax, but now in django-rest-swagger==2.1.1 don't work this syntax.

can anyone help me?

Perhaps i should use get_customizations in OpenAPIRenderer class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For adding query parameters to swagger please, go through [this](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/604) post